# Как передать числа из массива по отдельности в функцию?

Tags: python

Есть небольшой код, мне нужно найти наибольший общий делитель у нескольких чисел(без фиксированного количества):

```
count = int(input())
arrayOfNumbers = []

for i in range(count):
    number = int(input())
    arrayOfNumbers.append(number)

myGcd = math.gcd(arrayOfNumbers)
```

При таком способе передачи массива выдаёт ошибку: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Я так понял, что эта функция не хочет принимать массив, а ей нужны числа через запятую. Как можно передать числа из массива как отдельные числа? Функция gcd через астерикс принимает int числа.

Ответ: надо передавать `math.gcd(*arrayOfNumbers)`

Comment: `math.gcd(*array)`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так и передавайте два числа с нужными индексами

```
myGcd = math.gcd(arrayOfNumbers[0], arrayOfNumbers[1])
```

А, в 3.9 появилась возможность всё разу обработать - тогда "распакуйте" список `*arrayOfNumbers`

Comment: Так а я и говорю, что количество переменных разное всё время(в переменную count записывается их количество).

Comment: Индексы меняйте в пределах count

Comment: То есть мне все время код менять, чтобы разное количество переменных передавать? Не в этом проблема, мне хотелось, чтобы можно было передавать разное количество переменных.

Comment: Я понял,  у меня в старом питоне только два аргумента. Используйте распаковку.